# Erroneous output on recursive function in C

Tags: c, visual-studio-2012, recursion

I am supposed to make a recursive function that prints an integer digit by digit using putchar() and not printf. The output should be 1234 but I am getting 1234(smiley face)1234. Why is this so?

Also, can you add a '\n' outside of a printf?

Many thanks.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int printnumber();

int main()
{
    int n = 1234;
    printnumber(n);
    return 0; 
}

int printnumber(int n) {
    int x, y;
    x = flip(n) % 10;
    putchar(x);
    y = flip(n) / 10;
    if (y < 0)
        printnumber(y);
}

int flip(int n)
{
    if (n < 0) {
        putchar('-');
        n = -n;
    }
    if (n / 10)
        flip(n / 10);
    putchar(n % 10 + '0');
}
```

Comment: I can see no return value in `int flip(int n)`. Then how you can write `x = flip(n) % 10;`?

Comment: you went too far. 2 recursive functions is one too much for this task.

Comment: How do `n` and `y` become negative using division and modulo?

Answer (score 2):

Your code has undefined behaviour because function flip declared as having return type `int` actually returns nothing.

Also it seems that function flip does all the job. So it is not clear what is the sense of function printnumber.

You could simply define the function the following way

```
#include <stdio.h>

void print_number( int n )
{
    if ( n < 0 ) 
    {
        putchar('-');
        n = -n;
    }

    if ( n / 10 ) print_number( n / 10 );
    putchar( n % 10 + '0' );
}

int main(void) 
{
    print_number( -1234 );


    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
-1234
```

Comment: just realised mine is almost identical, except I use `(n > 10)` instead of `(n / 10)` as the conditional, thereby avoiding two divisions.

Comment: @Alnitak There is nothing suprising because straightforward aprroaches look similar do not they?

Comment: It wasn't surprise as such, I just wouldn't have bothered writing mine if I had spotted yours first.

Comment: @Alnitak Usually each of us does it for itself.:)

Comment: @Alnitak By the way as I never used function div then I forgot that such a function exists. Thanks that you have reminded me.:)

Comment: you're welcome.  Curiously, in _theory_ an x86 processor can calculate the quotient and remainder in one instruction (`idivl`) but GCC appears to be incapable of inlining the `div` function and makes a function call instead.

Comment: @Alnitak  And does the function use idivl or there is some overhead? If I am not mistaken the result shall be in register pair edx:eax.

Comment: I've not found the actual implementation yet.  Without the `div` call GCC and CLANG both appear to use nasty bit-twiddling hacks to perform the division instead of a plain `idiv` instruction.

Answer (score 1):

In your code,

```
x = flip(n) % 10;
```

Line invokes undefined behaviour.

You did not `return` any value from `int flip(int n)`. So, while executing the above stement, the compiler will have no explicit return value from `flip(n)` call and hence, the result is undefined.

***Related Reading:*** From the `C99` specification document, chapter 6.9.1, paragraph 12

> If the } that terminates a function is reached, and the value of the function call is used by
>   the caller, the behavior is undefined.

Note: Think of a simpler logic. This is kind of *overkill* for printing the digits.

Comment: @kits `can you add a '\n' outside of a printf?`..can you please elaborate this part?

Answer (score 1):

That code looks way too complicated.  Here's my single function version:

```
void printNumber(int n) {
    if (n < 0) {
        putchar('-');
        printNumber(-n);
    } else {
        if (n >= 10) {
            printNumber(n / 10);
        }
        putchar('0' + (n % 10));
    }
}
```

i.e. output `-` and recurse for negative numbers, otherwise using inverted recursion (so that the digits come out in the right order) first recursively calls itself for the leftmost digits and then prints the rightmost digit.

It's also possible to avoid the separate divide and modulus operations using the standard `div` function that produces both in one step, although whether this is more efficient is implementation dependent.

```
void printNumber(int n) {
    if (n < 0) {
        putchar('-');
        printNumber(-n);
    } else {
        div_t d = div(n, 10);
        if (d.quot) {
            printNumber(d.quot);
        }
        putchar('0' + d.rem);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Alnitak. In the first recursive call the argument is (-n). But before that we have putchar('-'). So we already determined it was negative ahead of time. Therefore in printnumber(-n), why doesn't the negative cancel out and become positive?

Comment: Try `printNumber(INT_MIN)`.  Infinite loop?

Comment: @chux I suspect most of the implementations here have that problem, since `-INT_MIN` is actually 1 more than `INT_MAX`.

Comment: Agree most answers have a problem with `INT_MIN`.  At least 2 do not.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is what you intend to do. While using recursive functions the lines after the recursive function call are pushed onto the stack so we can make use of it and print 1234 as shown below.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void printnumber();

int main()
{
    int n = 1234;
    printnumber(n);
    return 0; 
}

void printnumber(int n) {
    char ch;
    int x;
    if(n == 0)
    return;
    else
    {
       x = n % 10;
       n = n/10;
       ch = x + '0';
       printnumber(n);
       putchar(ch);
    }
}
```

Comment: **digit by digit using putchar() and not printf**

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Ok putchar is used

Comment: 1) `printnumber()` return type should be `void`, not `int`.  2)  `printnumber(0)` prints "nothing".  3)  `printnumber(-1)` does not print "-1" .

Answer (score 0):

Is there any need of flip() function ? You can check this...

```
#include <stdio.h>

void printnumber(int n);

int main()
{
    int n = -1234;
    printnumber(n);
    return 0;
}

void printnumber(int n) {
    if(n/10==0)
    {
        if(n<0)
        {
            putchar('-');
            n=-n;
        }
        putchar(n+'0');
        return;
    }
    int x, y;
    x=n%10;
    if(x<0)
    x=-x;
    printnumber(n/10);
    putchar(x+'0');
}
```

Comment: I can just check it in main function before calling printnumber().@chux

Comment: 2) => no, it will not be problem, n will never be INT_MIN. It will always be a single digit. :) 

1) => That's my bad... Void was in my mind, but forgot to write that. @chux

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67651/discussion-between-chux-and-mukit-chowdhury).

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want :

- a function taking an int and displayint it
- calling a recursive function printing digit by digit
- display adds a new line (`\n`) after the number

But as your functions do not return anything of interest it is better to declare them void. It would have avoided the undefined behaviour of using the value of a function without any return (`x = flip(n) % 10;` in printnumber)

You can do for example :

```
#include <stdio.h>

/* function declaration before usage */
void flip(int n);
void printnumber(int n)

int main()
{
    int n = 1234;
    printnumber(n);
    return 0; 
}

/* prints a int followed by new line */
void printnumber(int n) {
    if (n < 0) {
        putchar('-');
        n = -n;
    }
    flip(n);
    putchar('\n');
}

/* recursively prints decimal digits of an int */
void flip(int n)
{
    if (n / 10)
        flip(n / 10);
    putchar(n % 10 + '0');
}
```

EDIT per comment : if you want only one function, you should better put in main what should happen only once :

```
#include <stdio.h>

/* function declaration before usage */
void printnumber(int n)

int main()
{
    int n = 1234;
    if (n < 0) {
        putchar('-');
        n = -n;
    }
    printnumber(n);
    putchar('\n');
    return 0; 
}

/* recursively prints decimal digits of an int */
void printnumber(int n)
{
    if (n / 10)
        printnumber(n / 10);
    putchar(n % 10 + '0');
}
```

Comment: This is great but can I make the recursion occur in the printnumber function?

Comment: @kits If the purpose is just to print out the numbers using `putchar()` yes you can just use one function `printnumbers()` and print out

Comment: I separated in 2 functions one recursive that only print digits and one non recursive for only 1 reason : you did it. But you should keep the newline outside of the recursive function, and also the negative test (I forgot to do in first version) to avoid repeating useless tests at each iteration.

Answer (score 0):

Answering your easier question first, you can use `putchar('\n')` to output a newline. printf just repeatedly calls putchar.

Your code is a little over complex, and among other things flip() doesn't return a value (Always switch on compiler warnings - they tell you when you're doing something silly (or dangerous)).

An implementation would be something like this:

```
#inclde <stdio.h>

void print_digits(unsigned n)
{
    if (n >= 10) { print_digits(n / 10); }
    putchar(n % 10 + '0');
}

void printnumber(int n)
{
    /* Copes with max negative integer */
    unsigned u = n;
    if (n < 0) { putchar('-'); u = -u; }
    print_digits(u);
}

int main(void)
{
    int n = 1234;
    print_number(n);
    putchar('\n');
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Two issues

1. Using the return value from `int flip()`, but the function failing to provide a return value invokes undefined behavior (UB) - anything can happen.  [@Sourav Ghosh](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27634168/2410359000000)
2. `n = -n;` is a niche problem also.  When `n == INT_MIN` on many systems which use 2's complement integer, the result is also UB.  To solve that, negate positive numbers and recurse with negative numbers. With `int`, the range of negative numbers is always at least or greater than the range of positive numbers.

Add `'\n'` outside of a printf with another `putchar()`.

```
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>

static void printdigit(int n) {
  if (n <= -10) {
    printdigit(n / 10);
  }
  putchar('0' - n % 10);  // use -
}

void printnumber(int n) {
  if (n < 0) {
    putchar('-');
  } else {
    n = -n;
  }
  printdigit(n);
  putchar('\n');
}
int main(void) {
  printnumber(1234);
  printnumber(-1234);
  printnumber(INT_MIN);
  printnumber(INT_MAX);
  printnumber(0);
  return 0;
}
```

Output

```
1234
-1234
-2147483648
2147483647
0
```